# How do I see if an index value has multiple entries in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has user ids, but the ids can show up multiple times in the df if they submitted multiple entries. There is another column that shows what level the user participated in. I need to see if the user participated in multiple levels, so how can I do that?

```
ids=[]
for i in ids_lvl.anon_id:
   if i not in ids:
       ids.append(i)
```

This is what I have so far, but all it does is put all the unique ids into a list. How can I check what is in the list with the entries in the level column to see if the user participated in multiple levels. Thanks.

Edit:

| anond_id | L1 | level_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| az8 | Korean | 4 |
| az2 | Chinese | 5 |
| az8 | Korean | 5 |
| eu6 | Spanish | 3 |

Here is a sample of some of the data I am using. I need to see how many levels each user participated in. User az8 participated twice, so that is what I need to record. How can I go through the whole dataframe and seeing what levels each user participated in? I need to be able to get the total number of participants that participated in all three levels (3,4,5).

Comment: Can you please provide the source for the data or an example of the data if possible?

Comment: Have you had a look at the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.unique.html or https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html?highlight=unique#pandas.unique.

Comment: If you want to know how many times an id occurs: ```df_ids = df.groupby('id')['id'].count()```.

Comment: Or `df['id'].value_counts()`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you have 2 columns:

- user_ids.(ids can be duplicate)
- multiple_levels.(int numbers)

If you want to see different levels for each user id, you should use a group by.

```
user_id_multilevel_group_by = data.groupby(['user_id','multiple_levels']).size().
```

The result will be for each user_id, you will be able to see the multiple_levels and the count of occurrences of the multiple level.